# Right block order

Tags: layout, sidebar

On www.uitverkoop.tips I have now on the right sidebar 3 blocks. The block that i made on my own and recent viewed products and related products. Now I want to change the order. I want my own block on the top on all pages and then the other blocks.

I have made a layout.xml but something is wrong. Can someone help me with the whole code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * local.xml
 *
 * Local layout modifications for our local theme
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     my_theme_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2011 Magebase.
 */
-->
<layout version="0.1.0">
<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <alias>pt002-banner-right</alias>
    </action>
    <action method="insert">
        <blockName>pt002-banner-right</blockName>
        <siblingName>right.reports.product.viewed</siblingName>
        <after>0</after>
    </action>
</reference>
</layout>
```

Comment: Could you post your layout xml file here?

Comment: Hi, I can't upload here. But the code of the layout.xml is above

Comment: @marius do you have an idea

Answer (score 0):

http://inchoo.net/magento/adding-static-blocks-to-specific-cms-pages-with-magento-layouts/     follow the instruction gives in this url. ot will helpfull for you

Comment: Not helpfull, because The block is already created and visible. Only the order must be changed